# How to determine the summability of decaying exponential times harmonic series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Consider the series

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \exp \left (-\sum_{j = 1}^n \dfrac{1}{j} \right ) \dfrac{1}{n}$$

How do you determine whether this series is summable or not?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: I have tried turning $\dfrac{1}{n}$ into $\exp(-\log(n))$ and combining with the exponential. I think I can use an upperbound by $\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ argument but I am not sure how to do this rigorously.

Comment: You should edit your question to include that attempt! That's very close to a full solution (it's exactly the right idea) and so it provides a lot of useful context that you _have_ tried this problem yourself, as well as where exactly you need helping ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{j = 1}^n \dfrac{1}{j}>\ln(n)$.

That gives you an upper bound for each term in your series.

[Bounds for the Harmonic k-th partial sum.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832848/bounds-for-the-harmonic-k-th-partial-sum)